# Apache .shared folder

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, http, rewrite

There are already a bunch of rules in my Apache configuration. What I want to add is the following.
There are some shared folders (.shared): /var/www/.shared/ and /var/www/.include/.shared/ and /var/www/.include/(.*)/.shared/. Now when someone visits http://domain.com/test.png it first executes the existing apache rules and will (when the file/folder was not found) look in those .shared folders.

So suppose I've got this filesystem:
/var/www/.shared/dog.png /var/www/.shared/test.gif and /var/www/domain.com/dog.png.
Now when someone visits http://domain.com/test.gif, it must load the test.gif from the .shared folder. Now when someone visits http://domain.com/dog.png it must load the dog.png from the domain.com folder (because the existing apache rules will be executed first).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mod_rewrite` module for apache2 and following rule. Following can be put in either virtual host configuation or in ***.htaccess*** file in `DocumentRoot` of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/.*)/([^/]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/.shared/%2
```

What this does essentially is check if file exists, if it does not then split your `REQUEST_URI` that looks like ...

`/directory/sub/directory/file.png`

to 2 parts, first part is between two slashes '/' without second slash, and second one has *file.png* part .

`/directory/sub/directory` `file.png`

This then allows you to insert '.shared' in path of new request where you want to send user to.